# Pulling Blog Posts from Wordpress with Cakephp

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

I've created a cakephp component called 'Wordpress' in order to pull the top X posts from my wordpress install on the same domain.

Which model should I use for something like this? I don't actually have a WordPress model, as obviously its a different database schema.

Whats the best way to do something like this?

EDIT: I found this: http://www.kyletyoung.com/code/cakephp_wordpress_component

However, I'd still be interested to know about this situation, where you connect to a non-cake DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to second database directly (Wordpress one), you can set up a model for a table from that database and set it to use a different database connection.

To do that, you have to define additional database connection in database configuration file.
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/922/Database-Configuration

And then set your model to use that configuration.

```
var $useDbConfig = 'alternate';
```

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1058/useDbConfig